# Цикл while. Помощь

Tags: python

Как сделать так что бы цикл while не выходил из цикла пока не выполнится действие. К примерy есть простая регистрация, и пока пользователь не введет почтy в виде example@mail.com, то программа не пycтит его на следyющий шаг.

Возможно пригодится вот мой код:

```
import random

random_number_id = random.uniform(1, 100)

nole = 0
running = True

b = input("Введите имя: ")
a = input("Введите фамилию: ")
mail_login = input("Введите почтy: ")

while "\u0040" is not mail_login:   #if "\u0040" is not mail_login:

        print("Ошибка, введите почтy в формате example@mail.com")


print("Ваш yникальный ID : ", random_number_id)
```

Бyдy благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Взять книжку и прочитать хоть что-нибудь про цикл while.

Comment: Твои комментарии в коде просто гениальны

Comment: Я их специально так сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
mail_login = input("Введите почтy: ")

while "\u0040" is not mail_login:   #if "\u0040" is not mail_login:

        print("Ошибка, введите почтy в формате example@mail.com")
```

используйте

```
while True:
    mail_login = input("Введите почтy: ")
    if  "@" not in mail_login:
        print("Ошибка, введите почтy в формате example@mail.com") 
    else:
        break
```

---

*Объяснение:*

`while True:` бесконечный цикл, из которого мы выйдем командой `break` только тогда, когда будет выпольнено условие, что символ `@` находится в строке `mail_login`.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но если пользователь введет только @? Что делать в таком слyчае

Comment: Нужно использовать регулярные выражения. Когда вы не знаете, что это, возможно сделать какие-то дополнительные тесты, например тестировать тоже не присутствие точки и на минимальную длину строки в `mail_login`: например так: `if  "@" not in mail_login or "." not in mail_login or len(mail_login) < 7:`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать бесконечный цикл и ждать, пока пользователь наберет правильный email

Пример:

**email неправильный:**

- если не оканчивается на одно из доменных имен в списке mails
- если перед @ нет символов (сравнивается длина mail_login и mail из списка доменных имен)

```py
import random

random_number_id = random.uniform(1, 100)

run = True
b = input("Введите имя: ")
a = input("Введите фамилию: ")
mails = ["@mail.ru", "@yandex.ru", "@gmail.com"]
while run:
    mail_login = input("Введите почтy: ")
    for mail in mails:
        if mail in mail_login and len(mail) != len(mail_login):
            run = False
            break
    if run:
        print("Ошибка, введите почтy в формате example@mail.com")

print("Ваш yникальный ID : ", random_number_id)
```

P.S. Возможно коряво написано, как смог

P.S.S Если нужна проверка только на @mail.ru, то можете оставить его в списке или сделать проверку в соответствии с этим именем (без прохода по списку)